# A strange print url when post form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

When I post below form, print below data on screen. What could be the reason?

I do not use these process of link to the screen printing and part of code. It shows me by itself.

Form Data: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1rwh4031/

Print out: (it's uncompleted)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <a href="http://example.com/?f=BulkSales">http://test.localhost/?f=BulkSales</a>
```

And screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieKAE.jpg

Extra Information:

I run on PHP and in localhost. Display error is open.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Currently I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Sorry for my English. When I posted the form only an url like an image is printed on screen

Comment: I suspect this is a 'dns' (domain name system') issue. Is there anything looking like this in your 'hosts' file? It may be useful to specify the operating system and webserver you are using. Also, what happens if you specify the full url in the form 'action'? i.e.  _`http://test.localhost?f=BulkSales`_ rather than just: _?f=BulkSales_ Do you have _test.localhost_ in you]r 'hosts' file?

Comment: Thanks for your tips @RyanVincent .  I use windows 2013 server and Xampp. All instructions commented with # in hosts file. And I use action="?f=BulkSales" in form tag.

Comment: Let us make sure that the webserver is finding your machine...please add: _127.0.0.1   test.localhost_     to your 'hosts' file. You should not have to reset anything. To test that it is working then go to a 'command prompt' (menu -> run -> cmd) and do: _ping test.localhost_ . You should get something sensible.

Comment: I will try with real domain i.e.http://www.anydomain.com. Is there a drawback of this process?

Comment: @RyanVincent When I try 127.0.0.1 working perfect. But If I try real domain name (like example.com)  I getting same error.

Comment: Ok, when you _ping anydomain.com_ does it return your server address? i.e. will urls end up at your ip address? i.e. is your webserver running at the address pointed to by _anydomain.com_?

Comment: Yes, it's return server IP

Comment: Ok, is your server port 80 accessable to the internet? go to [The Web Server and Website Monitoring Service](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.server-test.html). It will check that your webserver is available from the internet. Also, try the 'grc.com' _shields up_ and check that port 80 is open.

Comment: I apologise for giving wrong address. The address of getting this error is a real domain like example.com. when I ping to the server, I get a real ip address like 78.xxx.xxx.xxx.  Server port is 80. And accessable on internet. Ok. I will check this url .

Comment: I assume that 'anydomain.com' is an alias of your real domain name. As long as you use your real domain name in all the commands - we are 'good to go' :-)

Comment: Monitor result: 

Service type: http://
Hostname: example.com
Port: 80
Test performed from: New York, NY
Test performed at: 2015-03-20 23:19:31 (GMT +00:00)
Status: OK
Response Time: 0.315 sec
DNS: 0.189 sec
Connect: 0.126 sec
Redirect: 0.000 sec

Comment: Clear your web-browser cache. then enter the full url to your web page: i.e. _`http://anydomain.com?f=BulkSales`_.  It should show your address in the url field. It should get to the form process script. Ok, no input so you will see a response with lots of error fields. However, you will know that all the urls work ok.

Comment: I tried it never used browser but the result is same. Is that really dns problem? It is a B2B Project so I am sorry to not give the real domain

Comment: It is so weird but I get this problem only when I submit the form. If I Access directly to http://anydomain.com?f=BulkSales, the page opens without problem. @RyanVincent

Comment: Just make the 'action' field in your form the full url - it should work fine. look at : _http 'baseurl'_. You need to see what is being shown to the 'router' when the form is submitted. _var_dump($_SERVER)_ to see what the incoming URL's are when you submit the form.

Comment: From my point of view - you can now get your system working by ensuring that you use the full url in your forms and scripts. You can fix it to use 'short forms' of urls later. I don't think i can help much more. It is late here - Was fun. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue. My CSRF control class error caused. I use CSRF control a precaution for form reload. Thank you for your support @RyanVincent

Comment: Well done for finding the issue and posting your answer.